# Website not loading, says it takes too long

Tags: web

My website, [sarkelliancreed.comule.com](http://www.sarkelliancreed.comule.com), is not loading . I have tried it in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and IE, and none of them display it. It isn't a 404 error. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more details ? The site seems to be down for everyone: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/sarkelliancreed.comule.com

Comment: Yes, I checked that too. I want to know _why_ my site is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server seems to be online as I can load Javascript files from it, but it raises several errors related to requests to https://nikkomsgchannel

https://nikkomsgchannel/e?00690027005a00210036003600190026005d0054005900500…230058002b003700630020002a00470058000a0059002f002a005e002d002d002c002a0029

Comment: As far as I know, I have nothing from that on my site. As I am hosting it for free, it might be the provider that's adding it on.

Comment: That nikkomsgchannel is probably generated by my Rapport plugin. Your website seems to have been up yesterday according Google's cache. What have you changed since yesterday?

Comment: I can't access my tools in my cPanel. I use http://www.000webhost.com. This has never happened before. Do you think they just removed my site?

Comment: I don't think they removed your site, it would have generated a 401 error. This sounds like a configuration issue to me. How are you hosting your website ? on ISS or Apache ?